# GWT link button

Tags: gwt

How to I make a hyperlink that functions as a button? Or how do I make a button that looks like a hyperlink?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One easy way is to use the Label class. Just create a new label and add a ClickHandler to it. You can then style it however you want using CSS:

```
Label lbl = new Label("Hello");
lbl.addClickHandler(...);
lbl.setStyleName("hyperlink_style_label");
```

Comment: I have tried the Anchor approach, but for some reason the Anchor in GWT triggers a Window.ClosingEvent in IE. Not sure what's happening there. However, doing it this way with the clickHandler worked just fine in IE.

Answer (score 15):

As of GWT 1.5, there is an [Anchor](https://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Anchor.html) widget that should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I also found you can use the anchor class. add a click event and load the method you want as a new page. Inside the page clear the root or other panels you want using the clear() method eg. Rootpanel.get("root panel name").clear();

[I wrote the example up and gave an example](http://colchambers.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-multiple-page-gwt-app.html) if you want to check it out. Hope this helps.