# GWT Label like Hyperink

Tags: java, gwt, label

I want a GWT `Label` which acts like an hyperlink.

Basically, the label should have an on click method which when clicked opens up a website.I don't want to implement this using an IFrame.

Is there any way i can do this?

Sorry if the question is pathetically easy to solve.

Comment: Have a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076616/gwt-link-button . Another option, if you don't mind mixing libs, is to use the LinkItem from SmartGWT. Or, you can just use the HyperLink that ships with gwt.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest using [`Anchor`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Anchor.html), more specifically, via the [`Anchor(java.lang.String text)`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Anchor.html#Anchor(java.lang.String)) constructor:

> Creates an anchor for scripting. The
>   anchor's href is set to javascript:;,
>   based on the expectation that
>   listeners will be added to the anchor.

So, you'll get a good ol' `<a>` that on click doesn't do anything, but you can add a `ClickHandler` to it, as such:

```
Anchor anchor = new Anchor("Click me!"); // At this point clicking it won't do a thing
anchor.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onClick (ClickEvent event){
        Window.open("http://www.example.com/", "_blank", ""); // Or open a PopupPanel
                                                              // or sth similar
    }
});
```

I'm advising `Anchor` over `Label` for accessibility reasons - if it's a link, then it should be an `<a>`, IMHO. If you really need to use a `Label`, you can add to it a `ClickHandler` like shown above.